# Customising \cref references

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels, cleveref

I usually use the `cleveref` package for referencing equations, such as in the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{equation1}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{equation1}.

\end{document}
```

This comes out as "A reference to equation (1)."

But sometimes I write things in an equation environment that aren't equations, such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{isomorphism1}
G \cong C_2 \times C_2
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{isomorphism1}.

\end{document}
```

How could I change my code, so that this comes out as: "A reference to isomorphism (1)."

And more generally, if the object in the equation environment is a homotopy equivalence, homomorphism, any given equivalence relation, *etc*.

So far, I have been doing it manually in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{isomorphism1}
G \cong C_2 \times C_2
\end{equation}

A reference to isomorphism (\ref{isomorphism1}).

\end{document}
```

This works but is not ideal for two reasons:

(1) It is manual.

(2) The "isomorphism" part cannot be hyperlinked, if you want it to.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{isomorphism}{isomorphism}{isomorphisms}
\creflabelformat{isomorphism}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label[isomorphism]{equation1}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{equation1}.


\begin{equation}\label{equation2}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{equation2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I have one problem: When I add `nameinlink` to the `cleveref` preamble, it will not typeset.

Comment: @HeinrichWagner: Thanks for pointing that out. I hadn't noticed that. I have now corrected the `\creflabelformat{isomorphism}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3}` to also work with the `nameinlink` option.